# Skip filter for the first time during onload angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is there any way to skip the filter for the first time ? during onload

**Here is HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="style in styles">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="style.selected"> {{style.name}}
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="tour in tours | filter: hasStyle">Name: {{tour.Tourname}}
```

**Angular js**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', function($scope){
  $scope.styles = [{"name":"walking"},{"name":"food"},{"name":"culture"}];
  $scope.tours = [{"Tourname":"sky walk","style":"walking "},{"Tourname":"Accra markets","style":"food,walking"}];

  $scope.hasStyle = function(item){
    return $scope.styles.some(function(style){
      if(style.selected && item.style.indexOf(style.name) > -1) {
        return true;
      }
    })
  }
});
```

**Objective** :

I am using refine search for the results displaying , for the first time i want to load all the results .I want to skip filter or any other better way to display all results for the first time ?

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eeoBxLBkJt8VNyOEyK5x?p=preview)

Comment: Have you got any solution for this??

Comment: I guess, we need to design our data & filter in such a way that, filter should show all in the first time. anyway thanks..

Comment: Can you show me sample in fiddle ?